# Multiple dropdown list

Tags: angular7

I have multiple Dropdown list. Each dropdown have values from 1 upto 10.

In first dropdown list, if the user selects value 2, then automatically the value 3 will be shown in the second dropdown list.

So in the end, if the user selects a value from the first dropdown list, I must show the value, incremented by one on the second dropdown list.

How can I do it in Angular?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Hi sarita, try to change a little bit your question, it's not clear what the problem is. Is the problem a front-end issue or is it involves as well the server side?